# Is SelfPubBookCovers.com a good website to buy book covers?

Tags: self-publishing, marketing, kindle, book-cover

The saying goes to never judge a book by its cover, but let's face it: a cover is a very important part of a book. However, many people don't have access to an illustrator, or cover designer. I myself don't have the skills to design my own cover, and I've had very little luck finding an artist at my community college interested in designing a book cover for me.

So I signed up for SelfPubBookCovers.com thinking that I do like a lot of the covers, but they're anywhere between 60-95 dollars. This is a lot of money for me to put upfront, and I know that it could be worth it, but have any other self published authors had any luck with the book covers from SelfPubBookCovers.com?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. As a general statement, you get what you pay for. Whether it's art, a book cover, editing services, or anything else, if you're trying to cut corners financially, you will often pay for it on the other end with a poor quality product. I'm not familiar with the site you're discussing, but I think cavilling over $100 for the cover of your book is self-defeating. If you're self-publishing, you alone are responsible for all your marketing, and a cover is an important part of that. I wouldn't skimp.

Comment: What I found a little suspicious is that the site has NaNoWriMo banners and yet not mentioned as a sponsor. Also, have you tried Twitter, goodreads and even Wattpad? If you dig good enough there are some marvelous artists there who are lovely to  work with and take much lower prices.

Comment: Lior, would you care to give me some suggestions on artists you've found on goodreads, and Wattpad?

Comment: "What I found a little suspicious is that the site has NaNoWriMo banners and yet not mentioned as a sponsor. " For the second year in a row, SelfPubBookCovers is a proud sponsor of NaNoWriMo! The NaNoWriMo logo on our site, lists us as a sponsor. I guess it was too small for this author to have seen it. Sincerely, Rob Sturtz, co-founder, SelfPubBookCovers.com.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with that site, but you might want to try looking at [Fiverr](http://www.fiverr.com) to see if anyone offering to make covers there seems appropriate. While everything on Fiverr starts at $5 you will likely want a package that costs a bit more. There are multiple folks there who do covers, so explore and see if you find some one you want to work on your cover, then check their options.

Answer (score 1):

The business model of that site (I took a quick gander at the artist submission guidelines) is rather legit. They do require artists to submit original artworks, and if the stock photos are used, they ensure originality by making the artist use a combination of at least two images. Each cover is only sold once, once you paid for it, it's yours and yours only.

While nominally that policy ensures that the covers, produced in that manner are, indeed, all different to some extent, please, consider the following:

The artists submits their works to the site with one and only purpose--to sell them. In order for the pre-fixed cover to be sold, *it must be generic enough to fit the widest variety of tastes*, and this is what you have to select from: the wide selection of generic-looking covers.

Even if you will find the cover that matches perfectly the mood and other specifics of your book, you will still end up with a book cover which looks somewhat like the other one you saw, only the blond on the cover is a brunette and is looking the other way.

If you want something original, you have to work with the artist on the project and let them read your book first. That is much more expensive, though.

The choice is yours.